# Is there a way to use Apple Magic Trackpad (Bluetooth) on Debian Squeeze?

Tags: linux, debian, debian-squeeze, magic-trackpad

What do I have to do to get an Apple Magic Trackpad to "work" on a standard Debian Squeeze system?

Right now, the trackpad is connected to the machine over Bluetooth, and functions like a mouse: moving a finger on the surface moves the cursor, and pressing the physical buttons on the trackpad clicks appropriately. I'd like more functionality: specifically, tap-to-click and two-finger-scrolling. (Getting all the fancier multitouch gestures, like zoom/back/forward/etc. working would be nice, but definitely important.)

Kernel is the standard Debian 2.6.32-5-amd64. I have xserver-xorg-input-{all,evdev,synaptics} installed. The following is in `/proc/bus/input/devices`:

```
I: Bus=0005 Vendor=05ac Product=030e Version=0160
N: Name="jon’s trackpad"
P: Phys=00:02:72:21:36:85
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.0/usb2/2-1/2-1.2/2-1.2.3/2-1.2.3:1.0/bluetooth/hci0/hci0:11/input690
U: Uniq=C8:BC:C8:F8:FB:A4
H: Handlers=mouse3 event13 
B: EV=17
B: KEY=30003 0 0 0 0
B: REL=3
B: MSC=10
```

If anything else would be useful, I'm happy to post it.

Answer (score 1):

The most promising toolkit I've found is Fusuma:

#### Fusuma

- https://github.com/iberianpig/fusuma

A flexible way to configure multitouch gestures. You can emulate a lot of *macOS* functionality. 3 finger drag, swipe workspaces etc.

You can also setup application specific gestures.

Config is done in yaml, and the GitHub README has links to examples to help you get started.

---

#### Touchegg

- https://github.com/JoseExposito/touchegg

Also, there is **Touchegg**. This has a similar feature set, and may be preferable to Fusuma for some.

---

***Note**: Fusuma has a dependency on Ruby, which may be a sticking point for some.*